# Problems with FileInfo

Tags: c#, locale, fileinfo

I'm an italian user and I've these directories:

- Utenti (as Users)
- Immagini (as Pictures)
- Etc..

Now, **when I search a file with Windows SDK DSearch API**, I get this path:

C:\Utenti\\myfile.txt

and when I invoke:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Utenti\<User>\myfile.txt");
```

the field file.Length throws an exception (FileNotFound).
But if I use:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\<User>\myfile.txt");
```

file.Length works correctly.

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder....));`
to retrieve the folder you need.

If you get from somewhere else a localized path, you can try to match with the actual special folder localized to by looking at this question:
[How to get the actual (localized) folder names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145394/how-to-get-the-actual-localized-folder-names)
Basically this tour out in using ( interop ) the 
[SHGetLocalizedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762189%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: He can't, the path is returned by the Search API

Comment: @Guillaume you are correct, I read the question better: maybe storing a list of special folder path in a dictionary and then lookup would work...

Comment: Exacty Guillaume. But I wonder if there is a way to do it automatically.

Comment: @Cecco I improved the answer.

Comment: Thanks Felice. I try with this script and I'll tell you if it works. OT: Are you italian?

Comment: Isn't it the opposite of what Cecco is trying to achieve ? He already have the localized name and want to retrieve the physical path.

Comment: @Guillaume the strategy I propose is, create a dictionary starting from the SpecialFolders, with the regional names, then do a lookup with the received path in that dictionary.

Comment: The code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145394/how-to-get-the-actual-localized-folder-names doesn't work. This give me an error on GetDisplayName(String path), precisely within SHGetFileInfo(path...).

Comment: I'm searching but without success :(

Answer (score 2):

Well known folder and file names are only localized at the UI level. You have to access them via their correct names from code.

Maybe the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum helps you out.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. The Environment.SpecialFolder field give me path of "Users" directory, but the search snippet could return me also another directories (for example, C:\Temp or C:\Windows). I have to replace only path that have "Utenti" or similar (Images, Videos, etc...). I have to do it manually?