# C# get localized Path from Environment

Tags: c#, path

I have a german operating system and i need to get the path of a folder. In windows 7 the displayed name for "Documents" is "Dokumente". But if I take the path like

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

I get `C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\`
but I need `C:\\Benutzer\\Username\\Dokumente\\`

Any idea how I can get the localized path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145394/how-to-get-the-actual-localized-folder-names

Comment: The answer is where @Jcl suggested in his comment. Be careful what you do with this (string) value though. It is used for "display purposes" only. For example, if you try to write a file there it will either fail (because it doesn't really exist) or (worse, IMO) create the directory structure on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find that it is actually called "Documents" on your system. The "Dokuments" path is actually only displayed in Explorer (this localized name is referenced in the `desktop.ini` file). So the path that `Environment.GetFolderPath` returns is actually correct and usable. You can see the "real" names by opening up `cmd` and running `dir /a` within your profile directory.

Comment: I know that the path i get from Environment.GetFolderPath works. But in this case i really need the displayed-name.

Comment: To get the displayed name you will have to do this manually. You'll have to parse the `desktop.ini` for the `LocalizedResourceName`, then extract the String Table resource specified. It's doable but does require implementing some PInvoke calls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern int SHGetFolderPath(
            IntPtr hwndOwner, 
            int nFolder, 
            IntPtr hToken,
            uint dwFlags, 
            [Out] StringBuilder pszPath
            );

    public static string GetLocalizedPath(Environment.SpecialFolder folder)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, (int)folder, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0000, builder);
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: -1 It does not return the localized path as requested in the question, instead you still get it in English as it's the default localization for the system regardless user's culture. Consider updating your answer and let me know so I will remove my negative feedback.