# System.Environment.GetFolderPath localized path?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I am working on a Unity game and I'm trying to save screenshots in the Pictures folder.

The issue is System.Environment.GetFolderPath always returns the English version. This does not work on machines with a different system language. What am I missing?

Here's the

```
code 
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures) +
                                                "/Screenshot/" + "Screenshot_" + System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Is it actually not working? Because afaik windows still underlying uses english names for the folders, they only change display names in the UI accordingly

Comment: If you mean that the value doesn't represent the text shown in e.g explorer then this doesn't matter because if e.g you navigate to your `Screenshot` folder and click in the navigation bar you will see the "real" name of the folder

Comment: I think even further for those special folders the user can actually manually re-point them to different locations (see properties -> location for getting the actual path)

Comment: similar questions have been asked several times already. Have a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685261/c-sharp-get-localized-path-from-environment) and maybe it helps you out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# get localized Path from Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685261/c-sharp-get-localized-path-from-environment)

Comment: thanks for all your replies!
@derHugo I thought so as well but the log says otherwise

Failed to store screen shot (C:\Users\Riccardo\Pictures/Screenshot/Screenshot_20230726_030940.jpg)

Comment: You could also try Unity's own API to get the persistent data path, and from there navigate to the "Pictures" folder instead of relying on Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures.