# How to get the localized special folder name?

Tags: c#, winapi, shell, localization, globalization

I use `SHGetFileInfo()` or `GetDisplayNameOf()` to get the name of a special folder.

If a localized operating system to change the setting "Current language for non-Unicode programs", these functions return a value "??? ?????????".

This combination of settings encountered by users.

shell32 is not fully unicode compatible?

```
Shell32.STRRET STRRET;
STRRET.uType = (uint)Shell32.STRRET_TYPE.STRRET_WSTR;
if (Windows.S_OK != ishellfolder_parent.GetDisplayNameOf(ptr_pidllast, (uint)Shell32.SHGNO.SHGDN_NORMAL | (uint)Shell32.SHGNO.SHGDN_INFOLDER, out STRRET))
                return null;

StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder(260);
Shell32.StrRetToBuf(ref STRRET, ptr_pidllast, sbuilder, (uint)sbuilder.Capacity);
```

what is wrong?

***added later
Another example to demonstrate my question:

```
public static partial class Program
{
    const Int32 CSIDL_DESKTOP = (0x0000);
    const uint SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200;     // get display name
    const uint SHGFI_PIDL = 0x000000008;     // pszPath is a pidl

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public static int NAMESIZE = 80;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(IntPtr pidl, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbFileInfo, uint uFlags);
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHCloneSpecialIDList(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 CSIDL, bool create);


    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr pidl = SHCloneSpecialIDList(IntPtr.Zero, CSIDL_DESKTOP, false);
        SHFILEINFO shfi = new SHFILEINFO();
        if (IntPtr.Zero != SHGetFileInfo(
                    pidl,
                    0,
                    ref shfi,
                    (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHFILEINFO)),
                    SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(shfi.szDisplayName);
        }
```

This code not correct. Some cases wrong return values, described above.
Can anyone help me with an example of the correct code, fully compatible with Unicode and works with non-default system settings?

---

Thank you all! After some experiments, and found a solution. My error was here:

```
Shell32.StrRetToBuf(ref STRRET, ptr_pidllast, sbuilder, (uint)sbuilder.Capacity);
```

The signature should be:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint="StrRetToBufW")]
public static extern Int32 StrRetToBufW( ...
```

Comment: Try using the unicode version of the function SHGetFileInfoW and then GetDisplayNameOf should return STRRET of type STRRET_WSTR.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was the first thing I tried. But it is not working. I checked on Windows 7,8. I added one of the examples of the code in the post.

Comment: How are you testing?  Are you writing the strings to the console?

Comment: Is `Shell32` a library you're using, or a class of your own making wrapping up the `P/Invoke` signatures? If the latter, can you show the signatures that you're using?

Comment: Rather than adding an answer onto the bottom of your question, you ought to post it *as* an answer (you are allowed to). You can then (after a suitable delay) mark it as the accepted answer, which will make it far clearer for those searching later to know that an answer was found. I note that the problem *was* in a P/Invoke signature, but not one of the ones you posted, so we didn't have much chance to help you :-(

Comment: Not allowed, reputation - 11.
But you helped me, pointing in the right direction.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, answering questions is a right everyone is allowed ('m sure I've seen `1`s)

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked the same question.  You can use the code example there.

[How to get the actual (localized) folder names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145394/how-to-get-the-actual-localized-folder-names)

Comment: If you believe the question is a duplicate, you should vote to close linking to the question, rather than posting it as an answer (I believe you have enough rep to do so - I think you can vote to close above 250)

Comment: No that is not an option for me :(  Where does that option normally appear?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misread the faq - you're allowed to close your own questions, but not others. It would still be better as a comment than as an answer though.

Comment: Question not duplicate, there is a significant difference.