# Why do I get the wrong SpecialFolder icon when using SHFileInfo?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using `SHFileInfo` to retrieve system icons for both files and folders, however am finding that special folders do not return the correct folder icon.

For example, the Desktop folder will return the same folder icon as a regular folder instead of the Desktop icon, and the MyComputer icon looks like an old Windows 98 icons instead of the Windows 7 MyComputer icon that I expected.

Why am I getting the wrong icon for special folders, and how can I retrieve the correct system icon for special folders using `SHFileInfo`?

My original code came from [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using), however it's been modified a bit. The actual code getting executed is still fairly similar though, and looks like this:

```
public static System.Drawing.Icon GetFolderIcon(string folderPath, IconSize size, FolderType folderType)
{
    try
    {
        // Need to add size check, although errors generated at present!
        Int64 flags = WinApi.SHGFI_ICON | WinApi.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;

        if (FolderType.Open == folderType)
            flags |= WinApi.SHGFI_OPENICON;

        if (IconSize.Small == size)
            flags |= WinApi.SHGFI_SMALLICON;
        else
            flags |= WinApi.SHGFI_LARGEICON;

        // Get the folder icon
        WinApi.SHFILEINFO shfi = new WinApi.SHFILEINFO();
        WinApi.SHGetFileInfo(folderPath,
            WinApi.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,
            ref shfi,
            (Int32)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(shfi),
            flags);

        if (shfi.hIcon == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;

        // Now clone the icon, so that it can be successfully stored in an ImageList
        System.Drawing.Icon icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();

        WinApi.DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);     // Cleanup
        return icon;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Error
    }

    return null;
}
```

With the call to it looking like this:

```
var icon = IconUtil.GetFolderIcon(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
    IconUtil.IconSize.Large, IconUtil.FolderType.Closed);
```

I get icons that look like this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to use a PIDL instead of a file name.

Comment: On top of that, you passed `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` which means "Ignore what the file actually is and just pretend that it is what I tell you." And your pretend file attributes are `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` which means "just a plain boring directory."

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, that does appear to be my problem. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @EricBrown Thank you, that is a good alternative way of doing it if I want to maintain the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag. I found a decent example of code using PIDL [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5145899/302677) if anyone else is interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag:

> Indicates that the function should not attempt to access the file
>   specified by pszPath. Rather, it should act as if the file specified
>   by pszPath exists with the file attributes passed in dwFileAttributes.

I thought [Raymond Chen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746318/why-do-i-get-the-wrong-specialfolder-icon-when-using-shfileinfo#comment27632448_18746318) provided an easier-to-understand explanation though:

> You passed `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` which means "Ignore what the file
>   actually is and just pretend that it is what I tell you." And your
>   pretend file attributes are `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` which means "just
>   a plain boring directory."

So to fix my problem, I just needed to remove the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag when I want to obtain a folder-specific icon.

[Eric Brown's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746318/why-do-i-get-the-wrong-specialfolder-icon-when-using-shfileinfo#comment27632009_18746318) also provided a useful alternative way of doing this using PIDL. An example of code for that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145394/how-to-get-the-actual-localized-folder-names/5145899#5145899).

Comment: Can you share how you get MyComputer's icon using this way?
I'm using the same method to extract icons and i can't seem to find how to extract the MyComputer's icon since it doesn't have an actual path.

Comment: @MaorB If I recall correctly, I found it using the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum. Try using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)`

Comment: i've tried it, but `Environment.GetFolderPath` method returns an empty path for `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer` enum because My Computer has no actual path.

Comment: @MaorB I'm not sure what I did then. I think the first icon displayed in my question for "My Computer" is the one returned from an empty string prior to the fix, or perhaps I just substituted the "C:\" icon for "My Computer".