# How can I get windows language dependent application path in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

I have used for getting application path using "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" in C#

English windows xp : C:\programe files\test\
so I expected portugues windows xp : C:\ arquivos de programas\test but i am getting same path like English : C:\programe files\test.

So How can i getting windows language dependent application path??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145394/how-to-get-the-actual-localized-folder-names

Comment: English name is `Program files` so are you sure the application is in the Portuguese program files folder?