# In Windows Node.js fs.readdirSync With Users Folders etc

Tags: node.js, nw.js

I've been developing an nw.js project and use node.js file system functions in it as normal. In my application there is a file manager and I list folders and files according to user navigation. In Windows, for example, if I scan drive C: I get the  Turkish named folder "Kullanıcılar" as "Users". I know it's real name in operating system is "Users" and just seen on the screen according to Languages. I can replace names of such folders when dispaying in my file manager but I'm searching for better solution if exists. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's an SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329794/51685) that reads the localized name of a folder in C# using the [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa) function which might help you along.

Now I know you didn't ask, but in case you want to know where the information is stored... It's within the directory, in the `Desktop.ini` file.

For instance, my Windows 10 installation has this in it for "Users":

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21813
```

And this for the Images folder within my user folder (bringing this up to show you the additional keys):

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21779
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12688
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-113
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-236
```

The `@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21813` points to having to read the [MUI (multilingual user interface)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/multilingual-user-interface-functions) [resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Windows)), key 21813 for the given file (presumably the @ means that it's in this file, not this literal value, but don't quote me on that). `%SystemRoot%` is an environment variable that points to the Windows directory.

The actual MUI files and their locations are handled by Windows (see the MSDN link above), but we'll just happen to handily know that the MUI file for the US English localization of shell32.dll is `system32\en-US\shell32.dll.mui`.

Opening up that file with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), we can search for `21813` -- and voila! We can find [STRINGTABLE resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/stringtable-resource) #1364 that contains:

```
[...snip...]
21812,  "Extras and Upgrades"
21813,  "Users"
21814,  "Saved Games"
[...snip...]
```

I unfortunately don't have `tr-TR/shell32.dll.mui` available, so you'll just have to trust me that you'd find the `Kullanıcılar` string there.

Comment: Thanks a lot but that is not a kind of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, the `SHGetFileInfo` solution gets you the localized name for any folder, and... that's what you're looking for, right?